# Element stay on hover like tha amazon help page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I want to make something like the amazon help page :

https://www.amazon.fr/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=nav_cs_help?ie=UTF8&nodeId=508510#nav-top

[image]

When the mouse is in one category we can see the concern content on the right

My code works almost, however, when my mouse comes out of the link the right div is no longer active

There is my code :

Html :

```
<div class="activity--js margin-card activity-card card card-body">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-3 help__titles-part">

<% @helps.each do |help|%>

<p class="help__title" data-id='<%=help.id %>'><%=help.title%></p>   
<%end%>
</div>

<div class="col-9 help__contents-part" >
    <div class="row">
    <% @helps.each do |help|%>

        <div class="col-12 help__content-<%=help.id %>" style="display:none">
            <p><%=help.content%></p>   
        </div>
    <%end%>

    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.help__title').hover(
    function () {
         $(this).toggleClass('help__title-active');
         Id = $(this).data("id");
         console.log(Id);
         $('.help__content-' + Id).toggleClass('help__content-active');
        });
```

Comment: try binding the event to mousenter rather than hover if you only want to fire it on mouseenter.  You probably then want to use a specific add or remove class rather than toggle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked it to be like the amazon example, which uses a mouseenter event, not click and definitely not hover.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  
  $('.help__title').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.help__title-active').removeClass('help__title-active');
    $('.help__content-active').removeClass('help__content-active');
    $(this).addClass('help__title-active');
    Id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $('.help__content-' + Id).addClass('help__content-active');
  });
  
});
```

```css
.help__title-active{font-weight:bold; color:red}
.help__content-active{display:block !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="activity--js margin-card activity-card card card-body">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 help__titles-part">
      <p class="help__title" data-id='1'>Title 1</p>   
      <p class="help__title" data-id='2'>Title 2</p>   
      <p class="help__title" data-id='3'>Title 3</p>   
      <p class="help__title" data-id='4'>Title 4</p>   
    </div>
======================================================================
    <div class="col-9 help__contents-part" >
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 help__content-1" style="display:none">
          <p>Help 1</p>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 help__content-2" style="display:none">
          <p>Help 2</p>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 help__content-3" style="display:none">
          <p>Help 3</p>   
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 help__content-4" style="display:none">
          <p>Help 4</p>   
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following jQuery to achieve the above mentioned result:

```
var list = $("ul");
list.find("li").mouseenter(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("active")){
    list.removeClass("active");
  }else{
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

I have used this dummy HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

I have used this as the CSS to make the code more understandable:

```
.active{
  background-color:orange!important;
}
li{
  background-color:blue;
  color:white;
  width:20%;
  cursor:pointer;
}
li:not(:last-child){
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vngazw9q/13/) supporting this.

But this will easily be reset once the page is refreshed as this changes the layout dynamically, its not fixed.

I hope this was helpful.